# collectively singular vs plural

Tags: grammaticality

> We propose method A and method B, which collectively enables
>   smart exploration of search space.
>
> We propose method A and method B, which collectively enable
>   smart exploration of search space.

Which one is grammatical?

Answer (score 1):

Without the word *collectively*, *which* might refer to either the two methods or your (single) proposal, so either a singular or plural verb would be possible.

But your (single) proposal cannot operate *collectively*. Consequently, the subject of *enable* must be the two methods, and must take the form proper to a plural subject:

> We propose method A and method B, which collectively **enable** smart exploration ...

---

Note, by the way, that "search space" almost certainly refers to a specific search space rather than some universal search space, so it needs an article: "a" if you mean any search space to which the methods might be applied, "the" if you are speaking of a search space you have previously identified.